# What is the best practice to replace a string on a URL

Tags: php, string, replace

What would be the best way or the best practice to replace a string on the below url

http://www.mysite.com/somefolder/123kf3lkf/abc.jpg

I would like to replace the value '123kf3lkf' from the above url.

I cannot use the basic string replace because the value on that section can be any thing.
The only rule is that it will be the section before the actual file name 'abc.jpg'?

I would like to replace the text on the above url to form the below URL

http://www.mysite.com/somefolder/mynewtext/abc.jpg

I require to do this with PHP

Comment: What do you mean with: "I cannot use the basic string replace because the value on that section can be anything"?

Comment: With PHP's str_replace ($search, $replace, $subject), I basically do not know what is the value that I need to search for. The only rule is to replace the value before abc.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
$replace = "mynewtext" ;                                            
$url = "http://www.mysite.com/somefolder/123kf3lkf/abc.jpg?test=123kf3lkf";
                                            ^-----   Note this  ---^

$find = basename(pathinfo($url,PATHINFO_DIRNAME));
echo str_replace("/$find/", "/$replace/", $url);
```

Output

```
 http://www.mysite.com/somefolder/mynewtext/abc.jpg?test=123kf3lkf
                                                            ^--- Sill Intact
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is as follows:

```
<?php
 $str = "http://www.mysite.com/somefolder/123kf3lkf/abc.jpg";
 $parts = explode('/', $str);
 $parts[count($parts) - 2] = "myNewText";
 $remixedURL = implode('/',$parts);
 echo "$remixedURL";
?>
```

[Codepad demo](http://codepad.org/gapuEkkv).

References:

- [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php).
- [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).
- [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest 2 more ideas:

1.Use `explode` and look for the LAST-1 place.

```
$url_parts = explode("/",$url);
$string2replace = $url_parts[count($url_parts)-2];
$newString = str_replace($string2replace , "somethingnew" , $url);
```

2.Use Regex.

Answer (score 0):

Regex solution:

```
$url         = 'http://www.mysite.com/somefolder/123kf3lkf/abc.jpg?foo=123kf3lkf';
$replacement = 'xxxxx';
$replaced    = preg_replace('@^(.+/)(?:[^/]+)(/[^\.]+(?:\..*)?(?:\?.*)?)$@',
                            '\\1' . $replacement . '\\2', $url);
echo $replaced; // http://www.mysite.com/somefolder/xxxxx/abc.jpg?foo=123kf3lkf
```